# How long would badblocks take on a 40GB disk? How do I optimize the whole procedure?

Tags: ubuntu, bad-blocks

I am running **badblocks** on a **40GB** partition checking for errors.It hasn't responded for hours now!

Went through some answers related to this and someone suggested to increase the -c parameter's value to optimize the whole procedure.
Eg:

> **sudo badblocks -svn /dev/sda3**
>
> **sudo badblocks -svn -b 512 -c 32768 /dev/sda3**
>
> **sudo badblocks -svn -b 512 -c 65536 /dev/sda3**

What is the underlying concept behind this and how does it help with reducing this procedures time?

Comment: Why are you doing this.  Just copy the data onto a new drive.  If its a 40 gig hard drive its _WELL_ past its use-by date, and amazing it has not failed yet.

Comment: Do you suspect your disk is failing/failed.  If it is. STOP WHAT YOU ARE DOING RIGHT NOW.  The first thing you should be doing on a failing disk is using software to bit copy the drive.  I would recommend using (GNU) DDRescue for this - and if it stops/jams, restart/reboot and try again in the reverse direction.

Comment: My bad! It's a partition of 40GB on a 1TB HDD,which I have maintained for ubuntu 15.10 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "-c" switch "*is the number of blocks which are tested at a time.  The default is 64*."

By doing bigger blocks of reads, you are reading and writing the disk more efficiently, which should reduce time.

It would seem strange that - on a 40 gig disk, and with verbose output you don't have any result (but I have not used badblocks for a very, very long time - SMART and syslog tell me what I need to know - and I don't use disks which are on borrowed time - so maybe I'm missing something)